# Linking Flask to PostgresQL

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having issues linking my flask program to Postgre SQL

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import db

app = Flask(__name__)

POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'user',
    'pw': 'password',
    'db': 'database',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': '5432',
}

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

@app.route("/")
def index():
   return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/register",methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")
    if request.method=='POST':
            name=request.form['username']
            password=request.form['password']
            connection = mysql.get_db()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            query="INSERT INTO 'userdetails'(username,password) VALUES(%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(query,(username,password))
            connection.commit()

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")
```

Register.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Project1</title>
</head>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</html>
```

I have already specified the DATABASE_URl when setting up with the credentials given by Heroku. I cannot manage to store the username and password into the database. The register.html page contains a form with username input field and password input field. Help will be appreciated.

P.S I know I left postgre details, they have nothing important. Just help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Mate, you should not disclose database credentials here. Even If you have nothing important.

Comment: `connection = mysql.get_db()` is not going to help you connect to postgres. I also don't see where `mysql even gets assigned/imported, how is this not raising an exception?

Comment: Thanks didnt know about stalkers here. :)

Comment: The problem is it doesnt show any errors, so I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Within the form element you should define the **action** attribute
e.g. `<form method="POST" action="/register">`

action attribute specifies where the data gets sent (source [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data))

In order to simplify using SQLAlchemy with Flask you can use the [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/) extension.
You can link PostgreSQL and Python by using a PostgreSQL adapter. A popular choice is [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/).

Comment: I edited that but I still am missing something. Please help me out, I couldnt find a solution for 3 days